# how to enable click with tr by index?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to enable click with tr by index? I have a JQuery code that disables everything with a table. however, I need to enable specific tr and its content by its index. My code of disabling is working but the enable one doesn't.

```
    function EditMode(i) {
        $("#GV_Table").find("input,img,button,textarea,select,div,a").off("click").attr("disabled", "disabled"); // working 
        $("#GV_Table tr:eq(" + i + ")").find("input,img,button,textarea,select,div,a").on("click").removeAttr("disabled");  // not working
        //$("#GV_Table tr").first().prop('disabled', false); 
        //$("#GV_Table tr").last().prop('disabled', false); 
    };
```

Comment: `$("#GV_Table tr:eq(" + i + ")").on("click", "input,img,button,textarea,select,div,a", function(){ $(this).attr('disabled', false); });`

Comment: `.on("click")` what are you expecting that to do?

Comment: @epascarello I need to enable one tr in #GV_Table selected by index.

Comment: @RyanWilson thanks dude but it still not working! I need to enable one tr and I tried this ($("#GV_Table tr:eq(" + i + ")").find("input,img,button,textarea,select,div,a").removeAttr("disabled");) and still not working also.

Comment: @MOHAMEDABUELATTA What I gave you works. It's called event delegation. If any of the tag types in the second parameter of `.on` are clicked, it removes the attribute disabled on that element. (https://api.jquery.com/on/). If you want further help. Put up example HTML and your function on `jsfiddle`

Comment: @RyanWilson Actually I need to make all elements clickable by executing the same function EditMode, not on click. moreover, It still not working with me. I'm still trying to fix this. please help

Comment: @MOHAMEDABUELATTA As I said, if you want more assistance I'll need more than just your function definition in your post. Go to jsfiddle, add the relevant HTML of your table into the HTML section and add your javascript function into the javascript section. Then add the link to the comments here and I'll help more from there.

Comment: @RyanWilson I think due to [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_off.asp) the problem is with off itself. as explained in the definition it removes click event handler so even after using on it will not be bonded with its old click functions. I thought it will just stop clicking but it remove it from the root.

Comment: @RyanWilson i think this solution is good. but it needs some fixing with the selector.(            $("#GV_Table tr:not:eq(" + i + ")").find("input,img,button,textarea,select,div,a").unbind("click").prop("disabled", true); )

Comment: I also applied this but it still makes everything disabled with no exception. '            $("#GV_Table tr:not(#GV_Table tr:eq(" + i + "))").find("input,img,button,textarea,select,div,a").unbind("click").prop("disabled", true);'

Comment: Please don't add code dumps to comments, it's quite hard to read, [edit] the question instead, and please read [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
    function EditMode(i) {

        //$("#GV_Table tr:not(.editable)").find("input,img,button,textarea,select,div,a").unbind("click").prop("disabled", true); 
        $("#GV_Table tr").not("tr:eq(" + ++i + ")").find("input,img,button,textarea,select,div,a").unbind("click").prop("disabled", true); 

    };
```

it can be worked using a class as commented or by passing an index number as demonstrated.